# How can I write simultanous data to csv file coming from multiple threads in Python

Tags: python, export-to-csv, python-multithreading

I am getting the mouse coordinates(mouse_x,mouse_y) from thread_1, which works with tkinter.
I have another thread(thread_2) working simultanously to get gaze direction estimation with opencv simultanously as (gaze_x,gaze_y)

now I want to write them both simultanously on the same csvfile, while not writing if any data is None.

I can obtain a tmp file to write to csv file from each thread, but cannot do it simultanously

```
with open(csv_filename, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect=csv.excel, delimiter=',',
                        quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow(["mouse_x","mouse_y","gaze_x","gaze_y"])

def get_mouse_coordinates():
        def motion(event):
                  x, y = event.x, event.y
                  tmp = [x, y]
                  with open(csv_filename, 'a+', newline='') as csvfile:
                          writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL) 
                           writer.writerow(list(tmp))
t1 = Thread(target=get_mouse_coordinates)
t1.start()


def get_gaze_coordinates
   .....
    gaze_x,gaze_y = ....

t2 = Thread(target=get_gaze_coordinates)
t2.start()
```

I tried to write to seperate colons but the csv file cannot be filled simulatanously....
I would appreciate any help...
Best regards

Edit: I need to record two data at the same time. Here I need to record the very exact position of the target (Mouse pointer here) on which the subject is looking at and the gaze direction of that subject.I need them both to be written on the same row for a given exact moment so that I can correlate.Does no one sample simultanous two columns of data for correlate?

Comment: "*now I want to write them both simultanously on the same csvfile*": Why would you do that? To get write conflicts? There is a lot of code written (and possibly hardware wiring too) to avoid this exact scenario (to serialize the writes). Fortunately, you **can't** do it, because of https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock. Also considering that disk access is very slow compared to *RAM*, it would be much faster to compute as much as possible in memory, and only write big chunks, to reduce the number of writes (although buffering happens at multiple levels).

Comment: you use mutexes (Locks) to let only one thread write at a time. 
you flush the file output to be sure, that always entire lines are written in a htread.

Answer (score 0):

To write data simultanously from multiple threads into a single file a synchronization mechanism should be created. For example - another thread:

```
queuForSync1 = queue.Queue(1)
queuForSync2 = queue.Queue(1)
t1 = Thread(target=get_mouse_coordinates, args=(queuForSync1,))
# in get_mouse_coordinates you have to: queuForSync1.put(dataFromThread1)
t1.start()
...
t2 = Thread(target=get_gaze_coordinates, args=(queuForSync2,))
# in get_gaze_coordinates you have to: queuForSync2.put(dataFromThread2)
t2.start()
...
tSync = Thread(target=syncThread, args=(queuForSync1, queuForSync2, fileName))
tSync.start()
...
def syncThread(q1, q2, fileName):
    dataFromThread1 = None 
    dataFromThread2 = None 
    with open(fileName, 'a+', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL) 
        while True:  # Here - a sync Event May be used to get out of the Loop and Join Thread Nicely
            try:
                dataFromThread1 = q1.get(block=False)
            except Exception as ex:
                pass
            # ... same for dataFromThread2
            if dataFromThread1 is not None and dataFromThread2 is not None :
                writer.writerow(list(dataFromThread1, dataFromThread2))  # Here data will be written Into File.
                csvfile.flush()  # Important
```

Additionally - if data from 1 thread does not change, while from thread 2 changes continuously - a buffer may be created where storing last data, received from thread.